# iCloud back up on iPhone 5c

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, backup

If I back all my data on to iCloud will this free my memory on my phone as I only have 8GB and would like more pics songs etc , hope people can help!

Answer (score 1):

Backing up to iCloud is only a backup, it will not free up space on your iOS device.. you'll need to free up space manually.

You can find more information on iCloud storage and backup overview here:
http://support.apple.com/kb/PH12519?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US